# Detecting HTML table orientation based only on table data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, statistics

Given an HTML table with none of it's cells identified as "< th >" or "header" cells, I want to automatically detect whether the table is a "Vertical" table or "Horizontal" table.

For example:
This is a Horizontal table:

[image]

and this is a vertical table:

[image]

of course keep in mind that the "Bold" property along with the shading and any styling properties will not be available at the classification time.

I was thinking of approaching this by a statistical means, I can hand write couple of features like "if the first row has numbers, but the first column doesn't. That's probably a Vertical table" and give score for each feature and combine to decide the Class of the table orientation.

Is that how you approach such a problem? I haven't used any statistical-based algorithm before and I am not sure what would be optimal for such a problem

Comment: is your goal to figure out whether it's Vertical or Horizontal? or it's just a step.

Comment: In vertical tables, can you have a a row with more than two cells??

Comment: Yes of course, despite the majority of vertical table act as the example. but there's many cases where the vertical table is exactly a horizontal table rotated 90 degrees CounterClockWise.

Comment: have you considered clustering!! I think it's the ultimate solution for you. I think it's even better than classification here. cuz your features is ambiguous so, have you considered it?

Comment: I am not very familiar with ML techniques, I can read a bit though, I'm working on java, if you know any easy libraries for that.

Comment: sure, the most famous and most used library is mahout form apache.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit confusing question. You are asking about ML method, but it seems you have not created training/crossvalidation/test sets yet. Without data preprocessing step any discussion about ML method is useless.

*If I'm right and you didn't created datasets yet* - give us more info on data (if you take a look on one example how do you know the table is vertical or horizontal?, how many data do you have, are you always sure whether s table is vertical/horizontal,...)

*If you already created training/crossval/test sets* - give us more details how the training set looks like (what are the features, number of examples, do you need white-box solution (you can see why a ML model give you this result),...)

Comment: the problem is I haven't used a ML algorithm before, if my suggestion solution of handwriting features and scoring them is close to ML this is merely a coincidence. So you see this as a clear ML problem? if so, I can look into the science and try to formulate a model. as for your question, my data is primarily tables from Wikipedia. if by training you mean having annotated data, then I don't have it, I can hand annotate some though.

Comment: and yes, the tables are either Vertical or Horizontal.

Comment: I don't think "handwriting features" should work - since it is a ML task to create such rules (you should "only" to preprocess data).  Is it ML? - yes, I think so. Try to read some basic stuff about ML (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning , supposedly, this should work for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning ), create training data, train some ML model (decision trees should work), evaluate ML model on crossvalidation data and you can deploy it into your workflow

Answer (score 0):

How general is the domain for the tables?  I know some Web table schema identification algorithms use types, properties, and instance data from a general knowledge schema such as Freebase to attempt to identify the property associated with a column.  You might try leveraging that knowledge in an classifier.

If you want to do this without any external information, you'll need a bunch of hand labelled horizontal and vertical examples.

You say "of course" the font information isn't available, but I wouldn't be so quick to dismiss this since it's potentially a source of very useful information.  Are you sure you can't get your data from a little bit further back in the pipeline so that you can get access to this info?

Comment: Actually the main orientation detection component gets heuristics from formatting and styling of the table, the component I am designing now is the one that should fire in case the table is plain table with no styling or formatting available. and This should be happening a lot in the data I am trying to design the detector for.

Comment: This is ten years ago, but if there really was a "main orientation detection component", you could have made a decent test set for this new component by applying the existing one to a load of formatted tables, recording what it found and then stripping the formatting to create your new test set with known orientation